# Finding the index of an element in a sorted list efficiently

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7, optimization

I have a sorted list `l` (of around 20,000 elements), and would like to find the first element in `l` that exceeds a given value t_min. Currently, my code is as follows.

```
def find_index(l):   
    first=next((t for t in l if t>t_min), None) 
    if first==None:
        return None
    else:
        return l.index(first)
```

To benchmark the code, I used `cProfile` to run a testing loop, and stripped out the time required to randomly generate lists by comparing the time to a control loop:

```
import numpy
import cProfile

def test_loop(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        test_l=sorted(numpy.random.random_sample(20000))
        find_index(test_l, 0.5)

def control_loop(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        test_l=sorted(numpy.random.random_sample(20000))

# cProfile.run('test_loop(1000)') takes 10.810 seconds
# cProfile.run('control_loop(1000)') takes 9.650 seconds
```

Each function call for `find_index` takes about 1.16 ms. Is there a way to improve the code to make it more efficient, given that we know the list is sorted?

Comment: Can you not use `search_sorted`?

Comment: Are you referring to http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html ?

Comment: Yes, if you can use a numpy array and it is sorted then this will be fast, you would essentially do `np.searchsorted(my_array, find_val, side='right')`

Comment: Even sorting it will be fast: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html#numpy.sort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard library `bisect` module is useful for this, and the docs [contain an example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists) of exactly this use case.

```
def find_gt(a, x):
    'Find leftmost value greater than x'
    i = bisect_right(a, x)
    if i != len(a):
        return a[i]
    raise ValueError
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I didn't know about bisect. I think i'm looking for `find_gt` rather than index here, though.