# How can I round the next number in a list?

Tags: python, list

Let me tell you what I mean. Let's say I have a list that consists of 75, 250, 525, and 900. And let's say a random number, 95. How can I round 95 to 250?

So far, I have only made it, so it rounds to the closest number but not the next integer.

```py
def closest(lst, K): 
      
    return lst[min(range(len(lst)), key = lambda i: abs(lst[i]-K))] 
      
lst = [75, 250, 525, 900] 
K = 95
print(closest(lst, K))
```

Comment: Yes, it will be least to greatest.

Comment: Simple: iterate the list and return the first number from the list that is equal or greater than the input. No idea why you think you need such a complicated computation here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python binary search-like function to find first number in sorted list greater than a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556496/python-binary-search-like-function-to-find-first-number-in-sorted-list-greater-t)

Comment: And if the list isn't sorted, then either sort it initially, or while iterating, remember the currently picked result number and see whether the other entries are smaller than that but bigger than the input.

Comment: Bisect catalog: [less/less or equal (unclear)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36143149),
[less or equal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2591159),
[index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23390917),
[C++ equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37873954),
[greater (this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66415225),
[greater (unsorted!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236906)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm old school.  I'd prefer something with a few more lines that anyone who sees the code can understand:

```
def closest(lst, n):
    for i in lst:
        if i > K:
            return i
    return None

K = 95
lst = [75, 250, 525, 900]

print(closest(lst, K))
```

Answer (score 2):

If your list is always sorted, you can use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html):

```
import bisect 
lst = [75, 250, 525, 900] 
k=95

>>> lst[bisect.bisect_right(lst, k)]
250
```

You will need to decide what you want to return when `k` is larger than all numbers in `lst` As currently written, if `k>=900` that would be an index error. Easily fixed with `try ... except` but you need to specify what the 'right' answer is in that case.

Bisect would be the best choice for large lists since it is written in C and super fast.

Alternatively, you can use the [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) built-in function:

```
>>> next((e for e in lst if e>k), default_if_not_found)
250
```

Same comment: you would need to define a default value if `e>k` cannot be found.

Comment: bisecting is likely always best with a list of any meaningful size! ..but note this should try/except or include a maximum value as it'll `raise IndexError` for values outside of it

Comment: @raid6n Having chosen this as the best answer, please make sure that for your own needs, you know for sure that K is always between `list[0]` and `list[-1]` and that the input list is never empty.  This code needs a check for those conditions if they are possible, as the current version will throw an exception if `K` isn't so well behaved.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the list is guaranteed to be sorted this should work, returning `None` if `k` is greater than all elements in `l`.

```
def closest(l, k):
    for i in l:
        if k < i:
            return i
    return None
      
res = closest([75, 250, 525, 900] , 95)
```